# How can I stream my desktop to another device so I have complete control over it?

Tags: trackpad, remote-desktop

I have a desktop Mac and I would like to work with it in different rooms without moving the Mac around. I am currently collecting options, this is information I gathered so far:

- AirPlay won't help me since it can't control the Mac.
- The [SteamLink](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6153-IFGH-6589) software on a RaspPi would be able to stream the desktop, however I doubt very much it is able to transmit gestures from my Magic TrackPad.
- [Apple Remote Desktop](https://support.apple.com/remote-desktop) could do it (I can run it on a MBP) but is targeted at sysadmins and not for regular, 8h/day work. I have no idea how responsive it is and I'm not entirely sure if it sends all TrackPad gestures to the remote Mac instead of acting locally on them. Also, the price tag is rather hefty.
- Generic VNC does not seem to support gestures according to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/341188/can-i-send-multitouch-gestures-over-vnc-to-os-x-lion).

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 2):

I'm working from home on an iMac, accessing two iMacs at our office through a VPN, and I'm using the "Screen Sharing" app that comes with Macs by default (at least up to Mojave) and is located in `/System/Library/CoreServices/Applications` (again in Mojave, I think they have moved it around depending on the version). I have my home computer with five Spaces, one work computer with four Spaces and a second work computer with just one Space.

It works pretty well, but any gestures that work with Mission Control or switch between applications are caught by the machine you are physically working on.

As a workaround, I've been putting the Mission Control application on each remote computer's dock, so I can bring it up manually and switch between Spaces, etc. on the remote computers. The keyboard <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>⇨Tab</kbd> does seem to work in that it switches between applications on the remote computer, so that might be a workaround for swiping between apps.

Answer (score 1):

ARD is your best bet. Although geared for Admins with large deployments, it'll work just fine for what you want. I used it for quite some time as a Mac sysadmin. As for Trackpad gestures, I used ARD only on a iMac with a mouse, so I'm not sure what will happen. Just my $.02.

Answer (score 0):

I use Jump - to work remotely on Mac and Windows machines as well as to provide remote assistance to clients. I've been using it for years and love it. (http://jumpdesktop.com). I access via my iPhone or iPad from anywhere. So that is what I recommend.